# Count future and past events with a time cut-off

Tags: r, date, dplyr, slider

I received a great answer to basically the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76017690/count-future-events-with-a-time-cut-off) but when I run the code on my actual dataset, it doesn't run and I get an error message.

This code creates a dataframe that exactly mirrors part of my actual dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c('111','334','334','334','334','334','888','888','888','888','888','888','888','888'), 
                 NoShow = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1), 
                 date = c('2017-03-04','2017-11-14','2018-04-26','2020-01-24','2020-01-25','2020-02-29','2018-08-09',
                          '2018-08-09','2018-04-10','2019-09-20','2020-06-30','2020-11-18','2021-08-13','2021-11-10')
)
```

This is the code I run to count future and past events with a time cutoff:

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr); library(slider)

### future no-shows
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  arrange(Person, date) %>% # slider unfortunately requires dates be sorted
  mutate(no_shows_next2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(
    NoShow, date, sum, .before = days(-1), .after = years(2)
  ))
View(df)

### past no-shows
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  arrange(Person, date) %>% # slider unfortunately requires dates be sorted
  mutate(no_shows_next2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(
    NoShow, date, sum, .before = years(2), .after = days(-1)
  ))
```

This is the error message I get when I run the "future no-shows" code:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `no_shows_next2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: Person = "334".
Caused by error in `slider::slide_index_dbl()`:
ℹ In locations: 5
! Endpoints generated by `.after` must be in ascending order.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `no_shows_next2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: Person = "334".
Caused by error in `slider::slide_index_dbl()`:
ℹ In locations: 5
! Endpoints generated by `.after` must be in ascending order.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─... %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
 3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
 5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 6. │   └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 7. └─slider::slide_index_dbl(NoShow, date, sum, .before = days(-1), .after = years(2))
```

I get the same error message I get when I run the "past no-shows" code:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `no_shows_past2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: Person = "334".
Caused by error in `slider::slide_index_dbl()`:
ℹ In locations: 5
! Endpoints generated by `.before` must be in ascending order.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `no_shows_past2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: Person = "334".
Caused by error in `slider::slide_index_dbl()`:
ℹ In locations: 5
! Endpoints generated by `.before` must be in ascending order.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─... %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
 3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
 5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 6. │   └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 7. └─slider::slide_index_dbl(NoShow, date, sum, .before = years(2), .after = days(-1))
```

I get the same error message when I don't attempt to change the dataframe:

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  arrange(Person, date) %>% # slider unfortunately requires dates be sorted
  mutate(no_shows_past2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(
    NoShow, date, sum, .before = years(2), .after = days(-1)
  ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to an edge case I didn't think of -- the date is  undefined when you add two years to a leap day. What's 2 years after Feb 29, 2020 -- Feb 28 or March 1, 2022?

Replace

```
.after = years(2)
```

with

```
.after = days(365*2)
```

or

```
.after =  ~.x %m+% months(24)
```